# Decision boundary calculation in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, linear-algebra

I am unable to understand how decision boundary is calculated once we get the coefficients of the model.

Here is the link that I am referring: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html

Here is the code

```
# get the separating hyperplane
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - (clf.intercept_[0]) / w[1]
```

I didn't understand `a = -w[0] / w[1]` this line.

Why we are dividing one coefficient with another?

Comment: Also, can you please point me to the basic algebra involved in this calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The separating hyperplane has the form `w[0]*x+w[1]*y+intercept=0`. So

`w[1]*y=-w[0]*x-intercept`

Now divide both sides by `w[1]`, and you get

`y=-(w[0]/w[1])*x-intercept/w[1]`.

This is exactly the equation that appears in your code.

Comment: Thanks Miriam for explaining. Seems like I should go back to the basics.